# How to replace bespoke code markup/tags with HTML replacement text?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

I have some bespoke bits of markup/tagging used within some forum posts and I am looking for a decent way to handle them (most likely using Regular Expressions, which I'm not too handy with!).

When I render the forum posts to screen, I want to convert the bespoke tagging within the text, converting them into real tags. There could well be multiple instances of each bespoke tag within a post that needs to be handled.

**Here are the examples I need to handle:**

```
[URL=http://www.mysite.com]anchor text[/URL]
[URL=www.mysite.com]anchor text[/URL]
```

Needs to be replaced with:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">anchor text</a>
```

---

```
[EMAIL=me@mysite.com]anchor text[/EMAIL]
```

Needs to be replaced with:

```
<a href="mailto:me@mysite.com">anchor text</a>
```

---

```
[IMG]http://www.mysite.com/image.jpg[/IMG]
[IMG]www.mysite.com/image.jpg[/IMG]
```

Needs to be replaced with:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/image.jpg" />
```

---

```
[QUOTE=username]quoted text[/QUOTE]
```

Needs to be replaced with:

```
<div class="quote"><h3>Posted by: username</h3>quoted text</div>
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [Convert BBCode to HTML - C# - Source Code | DreamInCode.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2661.htm)

Comment: Using 100 different replacements, using `<font size="...">`. Do not like.